# Why does Apache want to use xcode for installation resources?

Tags: macos, apache

When I try to run `./configure` When building Apache with no unusual options this is part of the output:

```
checking for APR... yes
  setting CC to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc"
  setting CPP to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E"
  setting CFLAGS to " "
  setting CPPFLAGS to " -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK"
  setting LDFLAGS to " "
configure: 
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
configure: 
checking for APR-util... yes
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

I don't have xcode installed, so why does it assume I do?  I tried running the configure like this after installing apple command line tools which includes gcc, etc. into /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc CPP=/usr/bin/cpp LTFLAGS=--tag=cc ./configure --prefix=/Users/<me>/it/apps/apache2/ --with-pcre=/usr/local/bin/pcre-config
```

And the `configure` works (although I'm running into issues running `make` that I think are related).  Why, when `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin/gcc`, would Apache insist on looking in `Applications/Xcode...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to really know why the authors of the tool made a specific choice without tracking them down in many cases, but this one shouldn't be hard to guess.

Xcode is how Apple distributes a working C compiler to each version of OS X. therefore checking in Xcode for gcc makes good sense to me.

As you correctly have demonstrated, if you prefer to install another compiler or store is elsewhere, the `configure` tool is happy to use another path to the compiler.

Comment: I see; I guess I'm in the minority not wanting the whole xcode suite on my disc (I thought downloading the command line tools would be sufficient for those who don't want the GUI--obviously it's a lot more complicated than that).  Maybe I should just bite the bullet and install it.

Comment: Apple's been better about letting the command line tools install and remain once you delete the majority of Xcode. The download is still 2GB, but you can free up well 1.6 GB by deleting the iOS platform and iOS simulator folders within Contents/Developer/Platforms